# What about arrows?

Tags: haskell

Reading through various tutorials about Haskell's various category-themed classes, we find things like `Monoid`, `Functor`, `Monad` and so on - all of which have dozens of instances. But for some reason, when we reach `Arrow`, there are only two instances: functions and monads. In both cases, using the `Arrow` instance is less powerful and more difficult than just using the underlying thing directly.

Does anybody have any *interesting* examples of arrows? I'm sure there must be some, but I've never come across any writing about them...

Comment: [Relevant](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114681/what-is-the-purpose-of-arrows)

Comment: Might arrow-based FRP qualify?

Comment: My understanding of Arrows in Haskell is that they more or less give you the language of circuits, where one component depends on the outputs of the previous.  You might ask how this is different from normal function composition and combinations, but normal functions can't carry extra context and structure with them, while arrows are more abstract and can.  This is why they're very popular in FRP, you can write effectful code that looks pure and can be reasoned about very easily.  They're also used in the Hxt library for streaming XML data through seemingly pure computations.

Comment: There's an argument that `Arrow` is a fairly poor abstraction between served by its own "typeclass hierarchy" beginning with Profunctor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[HXT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt), a library which is used for parsing XML, is a very good example for the usage of arrows (have a look how often the word `Arrow` occurs in the module names of this package!). You shall have a look on the great tutorial: http://adit.io/posts/2012-04-14-working_with_HTML_in_haskell.html

But it is also good to have the arrow concept for functions. For example the following code

```
((+1) &&& (*2)) 3 -- result is (4,6)
```

just works, because `(->)` is an instance of the arrow class (The operator `&&&` is defined in [Control.Arrow](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v%3a-38--38--38-)).

Thanks to the [arrow syntax](http://www.haskell.org/arrows/syntax.html) you have also a great tool to write complex computations in Haskell (it works as well for functions, monads and XML filters in HXT).

Comment: HXT seems quite interesting. Any comment on why most parser libraries are applicative functors (or monads), but this one is an arrow?

Answer (score 8):

I like to think of `Arrow`s as composable directed acyclic graphs.  For example, an arrow of type:

```
SomeArrow (a, b, c) (d, e, f)
```

... you can think of as a graph that has three incoming edges of type `a`, `b`, and `c` and three outgoing edges of type `d`, `e`, and `f`.

Using this interpretation, the category composition operations for `Arrow`s are like horizontal concatenation for graphs, connecting their edges together:

```
(.) :: SomeArrow b c -> SomeArrow a b -> Some Arrow a c
```

... where `a`, `b`, and `c` may be themselves tuples.  Similarly, `id` is just the identity graph that forwards all incoming edges to outgoing edges:

```
id :: SomeArrow a a
```

The other key operation is `(***)` which is like vertical concatenation of graphs:

```
(***) :: Arrow a b -> Arrow c d -> Arrow (a, c) (b, d)
```

You can think of that as putting two graphs side-by-side, combining their input edges and output edges.

So `Arrow` commonly arise when working with typed directed acyclic graphs.  However, the reason you usually don't see them that often is because most people mentally associate graphs with untyped and high-performance data structures.

Comment: Presumably `ArrowLoop` is the point at which the graph stops being acyclic?

Comment: This accidentally gets to the heart of why arrows aren't terribly useful/popular. We already have `Category` for things that compose, and declarations in the language Haskell itself for things that exist at the same time (next to each other), so all `Arrow` adds is glue for putting things next to each other together, and taking them back apart. The problem is the invertible glue is just tuples, which are unweildy. It's really the tuple's fault. Imagine if we replaced `<*>` in `Applicative` with `f a -> f b -> f (a, b)`.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Right

Comment: @Cirdec Indeed, I believe there is a proof (somewhere) that `Category` + `Applicative` is equivalent to `Arrow`.  This is another reason they don't see a lot of use.

Comment: I found part of a proof, http://cdsmith.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/arrow-category-applicative-part-iia/. It requires more axioms for the interaction of `Category` and `Applicative`, and doesn't go all the way to showing that for any `Applicative` `Category` is also an `Arrow`.