# Applicative laws for alternative class formulations

Tags: haskell, applicative

A well-known alternative formulation of `Applicative` (see, e.g., Typeclassopedia) is

```
class Functor f => Monoidal f where
  unit :: f ()
  pair :: f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
```

This leads to laws that look more like typical identity and associativity laws than what you get from `Applicative`, but only when you work through pair-reassociating isomorphisms. Thinking about this a few weeks ago, I came up with two other formulations that avoid this problem.

```
class Functor f => Fapplicative f where
  funit :: f (a -> a)
  fcomp :: f (b -> c) -> f (a -> b) -> f (a -> c)

class Functor f => Capplicative f where
  cunit :: Category (~>) => f (a ~> a)
  ccomp :: Category (~>) => f (b ~> c) -> f (a ~> b) -> f (a ~> c)
```

It's easy to implement `Capplicative` using `Applicative`, `Fapplicative` using `Capplicative`, and `Applicative` using `Fapplicative`, so these all have equivalent power.

The identity and associativity laws are entirely obvious. But `Monoidal` needs a naturality law, and these must as well. How might I formulate them? Also: `Capplicative` seems to suggest an immediate generalization:

```
class (Category (~>), Functor f) => Appish (~>) f where
  unit1 :: f (a ~> a)
  comp1 :: f (b ~> c) -> f (a ~> b) -> f (a ~> c)
```

I am a bit curious about whether this (or something similar) is good for something.

Comment: That category is called [Static](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.2/docs/Data-Semigroupoid-Static.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is a really neat idea!

I think the free theorem for `fcomp` is

```
fcomp (fmap (post .) u) (fmap (. pre) v) = fmap (\f -> post . f . pre) (fcomp u v)
```

Comment: If that proves sufficient (I'll give it a try when I get a chance), it suggests that the `Functor` constraint on `Appish` might be weakened while still getting something "sensible". Rather than `fmap`, this law could be expressed with a `dimap`-like `(c ~> d) -> (a ~> b) -> f (b ~> c) -> f (a ~> d)`.

Comment: This discussion seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668313/arrows-are-exactly-equivalent-to-applicative-functors