# Why does mutual yielding make ArrowApply and Monads equivalent, unlike Arrow and Applicative?

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, category-theory, arrows

[Here's the SO post I'm going to refer to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24668518/11143763). [Also, I'm going to use the same snippets as the OP in that question in order not to separate the materials](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24668313/11143763).

It is [widely known](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Control.Arrow.html#ArrowApply) that an `ArrowApply` instance yields a Monad and vice versa:

```
newtype ArrowMonad a b = ArrowMonad (a () b)

instance Arrow a => Functor (ArrowMonad a) where
    fmap f (ArrowMonad m) = ArrowMonad $ m >>> arr f

instance Arrow a => Applicative (ArrowMonad a) where
   pure x = ArrowMonad (arr (const x))
   ArrowMonad f <*> ArrowMonad x = ArrowMonad (f &&& x >>> arr (uncurry id))

instance ArrowApply a => Monad (ArrowMonad a) where
    ArrowMonad m >>= f = ArrowMonad $
        m >>> arr (\x -> let ArrowMonad h = f x in (h, ())) >>> app

newtype Kleisli m a b = Kleisli { runKleisli :: a -> m b }

instance Monad m => Category (Kleisli m) where
    id = Kleisli return
    (Kleisli f) . (Kleisli g) = Kleisli (\b -> g b >>= f)

instance Monad m => Arrow (Kleisli m) where
    arr f = Kleisli (return . f)
    first (Kleisli f) = Kleisli (\ ~(b,d) -> f b >>= \c -> return (c,d))
    second (Kleisli f) = Kleisli (\ ~(d,b) -> f b >>= \c -> return (d,c))
```

And until I've stumbled upon the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24668518/11143763) referenced above, I felt that this snippet was a plausible proof for the equivalence of `ArrowApply` and `Monad` classes. Yet, having the knowledge that [Arrow and Applicative are not, in fact, equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24668518/11143763) and the following snippet made me curious about the full proof of equivalency of `Monad` and `ArrowApply`:

```
newtype Arrplicative arr o a = Arrplicative{ runArrplicative :: arr o a }

instance (Arrow arr) => Functor (Arrplicative arr o) where
    fmap f = Arrplicative . (arr f .) . runArrplicative

instance (Arrow arr) => Applicative (Arrplicative arr o) where
    pure = Arrplicative . arr . const

    Arrplicative af <*> Arrplicative ax = Arrplicative $
        arr (uncurry ($)) . (af &&& ax)

newtype Applicarrow f a b = Applicarrow{ runApplicarrow :: f (a -> b) }

instance (Applicative f) => Category (Applicarrow f) where
    id = Applicarrow $ pure id
    Applicarrow g . Applicarrow f = Applicarrow $ (.) <$> g <*> f

instance (Applicative f) => Arrow (Applicarrow f) where
    arr = Applicarrow . pure
    first (Applicarrow f) = Applicarrow $ first <$> f
```

> [Thus if you round trip through applicative you lose some features.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24668313/11143763)

It is obvious with the examples written down, yet I fail to grasp how is "round-tripping" through Monad preserves all the ArrowApply features since initially we had an arrow which depends on some input (`a b c`) but in the end, we end up with an arrow forced into a wrapper which has unit type as its input type (`ArrowMonad (a () b)`).

It is obvious that I'm doing something awfully wrong here, yet I cannot understand what exactly.

What is the full proof that `ArrowApply` and `Monad` are equivalent?

What do the examples of inequivalence of `Arrow` and `Applicative` account for? Does one generalise another?

What is the interpretation of that whole situation in arrow calculus and category theory?

I would appreciate both full explanations and tips which could help one draw up a plausible piece of proof themself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> since initially we had an arrow which depends on some input (`a b c`) but in the end, we end up with an arrow forced into a wrapper which has unit type as its input type (`ArrowMonad (a () b)`)

I guess this is the central point of confusion, and indeed it is confusing. I like to think of arrows as mostly morphisms in a cartesian monoidal category, where you wouldn't get this, but already the `Arrow` class is actually more restrictive than that thanks to `arr` – which gives you a functor from **Hask** into the category. But, somewhat surprisingly, that also entails that you get a mapping in the *other* direction: any arrow can be replaced with a *function* which yields merely an arrow of trivial domain. Concretely,

```
arrAsFunction :: Arrow k => k x y -> (x -> k () y)
arrAsFunction φ x = φ <<< arr (const x)
```

Ok that alone wouldn't be too groundbraking – maybe we've just discarded some information here? – but with `ArrowApply` this is actually an *isomorphism*: you can get back the original arrow by way of

```
retrieveArrowFromFunction :: ∀ k x y .
          ArrowApply k => (x -> k () y) -> k x y
retrieveArrowFromFunction f = arr f' >>> app
 where f' :: x -> (k () y, ())
       f' x = (f x, ())
```

...which is exactly what's used in the `Monad (ArrowMonad a)` instance.

So the upshot is: `arr`, by requiring that you can embed any Haskell function in the category, enforces that the category basically boils down to *functions with some wrapper around the result*, IOW something like Kleisli arrows.

Check out some other category-theory hierarchies to see that this is *not* a fundamental feature of cartesian monoidal categories, but really an artifact of the **Hask** → *k* functor. E.g. [in constrained-categories](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:PreArrow) I've mirrored the standard classes closely, with `PreArrow` as the class of cartesian monoidal categories, but deliberately kept `arr` out of it and didn't make it specific to **Hask**, because that dumbs down the capabilities of the category too much and causes it to be almost-equivalent to **Hask**-Kleisli.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it makes much more sense now! Is there a reason why that part with the isomorphism is often left out of the consideration when speaking of ArrowApply/Monad equivalency? Or did I simply mistake an intuitive lead for a strict piece of proof?

Comment: Well, “monads are equivalent to arrows that satisfy the type isomorphism _A_ ↝ _B_ ≃ _A_ →(1 ↝ _B_)”... that's right there in the abstract of the oblivious/meticulous/promiscuous paper. Why this POV isn't usually discussed as much, I don't know.